# How do you deserialize a Json Schema using Jackson?

Tags: inheritance, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization, jsonschema

I need to deserialize a Json Schema (draft 7), but I'm stuck with `$ref`:

For all built-in schema types, I can use:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(value = ObjectSchema.class),
        @Type(value = ArraySchema.class),
        @Type(value = StringSchema.class),
        @Type(value = IntegerSchema.class),
        @Type(value = NumberSchema.class)
})
public interface BuiltinSchema extends Schema {}
```

But since a `$ref` in a schema means that all other properties are ignored, even `type` (see [here](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#ref)), it means that I can have a schema with not `type`, only `$ref`.

So a reference would look like this:

```java
@Value
public class ReferencedSchema implements Schema {
    @JsonProperty("$ref")
    String reference;
}
```

**Now, how can I write my `Schema` class to make it work?**

---

I tried using `DEDUCTION`:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(value = ReferencedSchema.class),
        @Type(value = BuiltinSchema.class)
})
public interface Schema {}
```

But it won't work since [polymorphic deserialization doesn't support multiple levels of inheritance](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1188) (so `DEDUCTION` then `NAME` won't work).

I tried using `CUSTOM` and `@JsonTypeIdResolver`, but it needs a single, not null property to be used as the type id, and I can't use `type` since it can be null when there is a `$ref`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution with a very simple deserializer:

```java
public class JsonSchemaDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Schema> {
    public JsonSchemaDeserializer() { this(null); }
    public JsonSchemaDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { super(vc); }

    @Override
    public Schema deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        final Class<? extends Schema> subClass = node.get("$ref") != null ? ReferencedSchema.class : BuiltinSchema.class;
        return jp.getCodec().treeToValue(node, subClass);
    }
}
```

You can register it like this:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonSchemaDeserializer.class)
public interface Schema {}
```

Then you only need to add `@JsonDeserialize` to the subclasses so that they use the default deserializer instead of this one (or you will get a... [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)Error )